# How to sort data by date from the earliest

Tags: sql

My data in database is in format YY/MM/DD so like 19/05/12. 
I need to sort data from the earliest and it should return in format DD/MM/YYYY.

I have made something like this:

```
select ocena,to_char(data,'DD/MM/YYYY') datka 
from ocena 
order by to_char(data,'YYYY')
```

but it sorts just within the year. I need to add somehow days and months. Ordering by `to_char(data,'DD/MM/YYYY')` does not work.

[image]

Data

[image]

Comment: `order by data` will sort correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just sort by the *original* column, not the expression:

```
select ocena,
       to_char(o.data, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as datka 
from ocena o
order by o.data;
```

I recommend using table aliases to make it clear that the `order by` column is the value in the *table* not defined by as a *column alias*.